# Vec of Vecs, where the inner Vec to only contain one type, but different types in the outer Vec

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to hint at an inner `Vec` to only contain one type of `enum` discriminant. I can use a `trait`, or something if that can work here too.

Is this possible, or is there another way of doing this?

Asking because I just want no accidental wrong type, even though the code can be checked during run-time, I'd rather have it at compile time.

```rust
enum Kind {
    Apple(Apple),    
    Banana(f32),
}

/*
This could also be two different types:
struct Apple { v: f32 };
struct Banana { v: u8 }; 
*/

struct Outer {
    inners: Vec<Inner<Kind::?>>,  // I want to specify that the Inner should be a specific discriminant.
    // Maybe an option of a T? where: T: Apple | Banana?
}

struct Inner<T> {
   // I want all these to either be `Kind::Apple` or `Kind::Banana`, or the same type.
   items: Vec<T> 
}
```

The other option I can think of is just expanding into the struct, and not use an enum.

```rust
struct Outer {
    apples: Vec<Apple>,
    bananas: Vec<Banana>,
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention there are values in the `enum` and the `struct`.

Comment: no, you can't inforce to use a specific variant of the enum.

Comment: If you could write your code with your second no-enum option, why would you want to write it like the first? What would be easier to do with "`Vec<Inner<Kind::?>>`" but harder with `Outer.apples`?

Comment: You don't need a Vec if every item will have the same value. You just need a count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `Kind` represents a domain of values, and `Kind::Apple` and `Kind::Banana` together are the entire domain.

`Kind` is a type.  The variants of `Kind` are values of the `Kind` type; they aren't themselves types.

It's a bit like asking if you could have a `Vec` of `i32` values, but specify at the type level that the `i32`s in one `Vec` must all be the same value, like a `Vec<0_i32>`, which doesn't make sense either.  You might as well have a `Vec<()>`, since you can infer that the value is 0.

If the enum variants have a payload, you could store just the payload.  For example:

```
enum Kind {
    Apple(Apple),
    Banana(Banana),
}

struct Apple { /* ... */ }
struct Banana { /* ... */ }
```

Now you could have a `Vec<Apple>` and a `Vec<Banana>`, but you'd just be storing values of those types, and the "kind" is inferred by which vector you get the payload from.